# how to maintain position of text during height transition?

Tags: html, css

I want to maintain the position of the text but when hovered on the div, the text goes down

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
<p>hover over the div element above, and the text goes down</p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
-webkit-transition: height 1s; 
}

div:hover {
height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: `position: absolute`?

Comment: @jacelysh I've tried it but that didn't work

Comment: text still moves even when absolutely positioned? weird.

Comment: @jacelysh got the answer check below-hiral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following to your css:

```
p {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
}
```

[**See DEMO here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/5hLhrdgd/).

Answer (score 1):

Add this..

```
p
 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 125px;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aLejh7w2/1/)